# Automatically create a table from object - sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-insert, create-table

Is it possible to automatically save all objects attributes (or filtered) to **Sqlite3** database? Or at least **prepared statements**?

My situation:

I have some objects, those objects contains tens of attributes so it is very uncomfortable to write statements like `CREATE` or `INSERT` etc.

My question is whether is there some more comfortable way to store the data in a database. But I don't want to store objects, I want to store those attributes as columns.

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = None
        self.id = None
        self.name = None

sqlite3_framework.create_table(Person,exclude=None)
```

This command would create a table whith **age**, **id** and **name** columns. They can all be `VARCHAR(1000)` let's say.

I think that f.e. Django framework can do that but it would be very huge overkill for me to use that.

Comment: It seems that you have two options - use a framework or write the framework.

Comment: Peewee http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html or SQL Alchemy are stand-alone object relational mappers (ORM) http://www.sqlalchemy.org/